# How come writeToFile does not write over original file?

Tags: ios, writetofile

I am saving a file like this in my iOS App in my UIImagePickerDelegate's method didFinishPIckingMediaWithInfo:

```
// write
    NSString* filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/invoice.jpeg"]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.0);
    if (imageData != nil) {
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

Then I am retrieving the file like this:

```
// load
NSString *searchFilename = @"invoice.jpeg";

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];

NSString *documentsSubpath;
while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
{
    if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:searchFilename]) {
        continue;
    }
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,documentsSubpath]];
    [self.imageContentView setupImageViewerWithImageURL:fileURL onOpen:^{
        NSLog(@"open %@",fileURL);
    } onClose:^{
        NSLog(@"close %@",fileURL);
    }];
}
```

The files do get loaded properly. However, when I update the photo (imageData) in my UIImagePickerDelegate and try to reload the image, I still get the original image written into my app documents.

Comment: Try to use the method that writes data to file and populates the error if any occurred, then you'll be able to analyze the issue. As of now you can only analyze the boolean return value which you don't seem to do, does your method return true or false ?

Comment: My method returns true.

Comment: If the full paths match and the write method returns true I don't know a better way than to replace your method `writeToFile: atomically:` with the alternative that provides you more information.